# Nesting one Object into another by key with Lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of events with the following format:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 20862,
        "Date": "2019-12-13T00:00:00-08:00",
        "StartTime": 1576220400,
        "EndTime": 1576252800,
        "Slots": [...],
        "TotalTime": 8.5,
        "Cost": 0,
        "Area": 29,
        "PersonId": 1,
        "Creator": 1,
        "Created": "2019-12-10T08:17:14-08:00",
        "Modified": "2019-12-11T06:11:18-08:00",
        "OnCost": 0,
        "StartTimeLocalized": "2019-12-13T09:00:00+02:00",
        "EndTimeLocalized": "2019-12-13T18:00:00+02:00",
        "ExternalId": null,
        "ConnectCreator": null,
        "AreaObject": {  ...  }
    }
]
```

And another array of Persons:

```
[ { Id: 1,
    DisplayName: 'Lex Luthor',
    ContactObject: { Email: 'lexl@dc.com' } },
  { Id: 406,
    DisplayName: 'Clark Kent',
    ContactObject: { Email: 'clarkk@dc.com' } } ]
```

I'm looking for a way to merge the Person object into the Event object by the PersonId attribute.
Eventually I need an array of Events that have an email address and the name of the assigned person :

```
[
    {
        "Id": 20862,
        "Date": "2019-12-13T00:00:00-08:00",
        "StartTime": 1576220400,
        "EndTime": 1576252800,
        "Slots": [...],
        "TotalTime": 8.5,
        "Cost": 0,
        "Area": 29,
        "PersonId": 1,
        "Creator": 1,
        "Created": "2019-12-10T08:17:14-08:00",
        "Modified": "2019-12-11T06:11:18-08:00",
        "OnCost": 0,
        "StartTimeLocalized": "2019-12-13T09:00:00+02:00",
        "EndTimeLocalized": "2019-12-13T18:00:00+02:00",
        "ExternalId": null,
        "ConnectCreator": null,
        "AreaObject": {  ...  },
        "PersonObject":{ 
           Id: 1,
           DisplayName: 'Lex Luthor',
           ContactObject: { Email: 'lexl@dc.com' } }
         }
]
```

Is there any way to achieve this with Lodash ?

Comment: In your final data structure, isn't `PersonId` redundant since you have it in `PersonObject` already? Maintaining two properties can lead to errors.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use lodash for such a simple problem. You can use a `Map` for O(n) time-complexity, alongside a `forEach` loop, if you don't mind mutating the original object:

```js
const events = [{ Id: 20862, Date: '2019-12-13T00:00:00-08:00', StartTime: 1576220400, EndTime: 1576252800, Slots: [], TotalTime: 8.5, Cost: 0, Area: 29, PersonId: 1, Creator: 1, Created: '2019-12-10T08:17:14-08:00', Modified: '2019-12-11T06:11:18-08:00', OnCost: 0, StartTimeLocalized: '2019-12-13T09:00:00+02:00', EndTimeLocalized: '2019-12-13T18:00:00+02:00', ExternalId: null, ConnectCreator: null, AreaObject: {} }]
const people = [{ Id: 1, DisplayName: 'Lex Luthor', ContactObject: { Email: 'lexl@dc.com' }}, { Id: 406, DisplayName: 'Clark Kent', ContactObject: { Email: 'clarkk@dc.com' }}]

const map = new Map(people.map(p => [p.Id, p]))
events.forEach(e => e.PersonObject = map.get(e.PersonId))

console.log(events)
```

Otherwise, you could just use slice and map the events array:

```js
const events = [{ Id: 20862, Date: '2019-12-13T00:00:00-08:00', StartTime: 1576220400, EndTime: 1576252800, Slots: [], TotalTime: 8.5, Cost: 0, Area: 29, PersonId: 1, Creator: 1, Created: '2019-12-10T08:17:14-08:00', Modified: '2019-12-11T06:11:18-08:00', OnCost: 0, StartTimeLocalized: '2019-12-13T09:00:00+02:00', EndTimeLocalized: '2019-12-13T18:00:00+02:00', ExternalId: null, ConnectCreator: null, AreaObject: {} }]
const people = [{ Id: 1, DisplayName: 'Lex Luthor', ContactObject: { Email: 'lexl@dc.com' }}, { Id: 406, DisplayName: 'Clark Kent', ContactObject: { Email: 'clarkk@dc.com' }}]

const map = new Map(people.map(p => [p.Id, p]))
const out = events.map(e => ({...e, PersonObject: map.get(e.PersonId)}))

console.log(out)
```

Comment: Interesting use case for `Map`; I like it. However I can't help thinking that `e => (e.PersonObject = map.get(e.PersonId), e)` while it's a nice one liner, it's also "wrong" in that it's absolutely not obvious to the reader that two things are at play here: injecting a new property _and_ returning the object. I would clear out the confusion with a named function tbh. But good effort nonetheless.

Comment: @customcommander I'd much prefer to use a map over find any day :P And yeah, I used the comma operator for brevity, I didn't want to use a spread, since that's just really redundant. I'm not sure about naming the function, but you're right about it being unreadable. If you want, you can add an edit showing how you would deal with making it readable :)

Comment: I think avoiding mutation is always the best thing to do as it can lead to bugs that can be hard to traceback. (Unless you _want_ to mutate of course.) So a cheap shallow clone with the spread operator can't be that bad ;) I added my own answer based on yours.

Comment: @customcommander I think in this case, it's fine to mutate the object, since I had just sliced the array just before mapping, hence why it doesn't modify the original array. Otherwise, you're 100% correct, it's generally a bad idea to directly mutate objects. I just feel that spreading the object just to add one property seems inefficient.

Comment: Careful. You have "cloned" the array but not its elements. Given `const x = [obj1, obj2, obj3];`.Then `const obj1 = x.slice()[0]; obj1.foo = 'bar';`  will mutate `obj1` in `x` too!

Comment: @customcommander You're right, actually. I'll add an edit in. Maybe spreading is a good idea :P

Comment: @Kobe is it possible to implement this function to map by Person email?
 `{ "lexl@dc.com": [eventsObjArray],  "clarkk@dc.com" : [eventsObjArray], "brucew@dc.com": undefined}`

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think you could do with just plain JavaScript.

I'd like to suggest a variation of Kobe's answer.

If you need to find an element in an array a lot, you may want to consider transforming your array into a map.

Here's a little curried helper that:

- Specify which key to use when searching for an element (see `k`)
- Transform your array into a map (see `.bind`)

```js
const findBy = (k, xs) =>
  ((xs, v) => xs.get(v))
    .bind(null, new Map(xs.map(x => [x[k], x])));
```

Which you can use to build a specialised function: `findPersonById`

```js
const findPersonById = findBy('Id', persons);

findPersonById(406);
//=> { Id: 406
//=> , DisplayName: 'Clark Kent'
//=> , ContactObject: { Email: 'clarkk@dc.com' }
//=> }
```

Then all you need to do is map over your `events` array:
*(Please note as per my comment in your question, that I removed `PersonId` as it is already available in `PersonObject`)*

```js
const findBy = (k, xs) =>
  ((xs, v) => xs.get(v))
    .bind(null, new Map(xs.map(x => [x[k], x])));

const findPersonById = findBy('Id', persons);

console.log(

  events.map(({PersonId, ...e}) => (
    { ...e
    , PersonObject: findPersonById(PersonId)
    }
  ))

);
```

```html
<script>
const events =
  [ { "Id": 20862
    , "Date": "2019-12-13T00:00:00-08:00"
    , "StartTime": 1576220400
    , "EndTime": 1576252800
    , "Slots": []
    , "TotalTime": 8.5
    , "Cost": 0
    , "Area": 29
    , "PersonId": 1
    , "Creator": 1
    , "Created": "2019-12-10T08:17:14-08:00"
    , "Modified": "2019-12-11T06:11:18-08:00"
    , "OnCost": 0
    , "StartTimeLocalized": "2019-12-13T09:00:00+02:00"
    , "EndTimeLocalized": "2019-12-13T18:00:00+02:00"
    , "ExternalId": null
    , "ConnectCreator": null
    , "AreaObject": {}
    }
  ];

const persons =
  [ { Id: 1
    , DisplayName: 'Lex Luthor'
    , ContactObject: { Email: 'lexl@dc.com' }
    }
    ,
    { Id: 406
    , DisplayName: 'Clark Kent'
    , ContactObject: { Email: 'clarkk@dc.com' }
    }
  ];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using .[..spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator, [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and  [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Try this:

```js
let array1 = [{ "Id": 20862, "Date": "2019-12-13T00:00:00-08:00", "StartTime": 1576220400, "EndTime": 1576252800, "Slots": [], "TotalTime": 8.5, "Cost": 0, "Area": 29, "PersonId": 1, "Creator": 1, "Created": "2019-12-10T08:17:14-08:00", "Modified": "2019-12-11T06:11:18-08:00", "OnCost": 0, "StartTimeLocalized": "2019-12-13T09:00:00+02:00", "EndTimeLocalized": "2019-12-13T18:00:00+02:00", "ExternalId": null, "ConnectCreator": null, "AreaObject": {} }]
let array2 = [{ Id: 1, DisplayName: 'Lex Luthor', ContactObject: { Email: 'lexl@dc.com' } }, { Id: 406, DisplayName: 'Clark Kent', ContactObject: { Email: 'clarkk@dc.com' } }]
let res = array1.map((value, index) => {
  return { ...value, PersonObject: (array2.find(x => x.Id === value.PersonId)) }
})
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need lodash

```js
const all = [{
  "Id": 20862,
  "Date": "2019-12-13T00:00:00-08:00",
  "StartTime": 1576220400,
  "EndTime": 1576252800,
  "Slots": [],
  "TotalTime": 8.5,
  "Cost": 0,
  "Area": 29,
  "PersonId": 1,
  "Creator": 1,
  "Created": "2019-12-10T08:17:14-08:00",
  "Modified": "2019-12-11T06:11:18-08:00",
  "OnCost": 0,
  "StartTimeLocalized": "2019-12-13T09:00:00+02:00",
  "EndTimeLocalized": "2019-12-13T18:00:00+02:00",
  "ExternalId": null,
  "ConnectCreator": null,
  "AreaObject": {}
}];

const people = [{
    Id: 1,
    DisplayName: 'Lex Luthor',
    ContactObject: {
      Email: 'lexl@dc.com'
    }
  },
  {
    Id: 406,
    DisplayName: 'Clark Kent',
    ContactObject: {
      Email: 'clarkk@dc.com'
    }
  }
];

const result = all.map(v => ({
  ...v,
  PersonObject: people.find(p => p.Id === v.PersonId)
}));

console.log('result', result);
```

But here's lodash version

```js
const all = [{
  "Id": 20862,
  "Date": "2019-12-13T00:00:00-08:00",
  "StartTime": 1576220400,
  "EndTime": 1576252800,
  "Slots": [],
  "TotalTime": 8.5,
  "Cost": 0,
  "Area": 29,
  "PersonId": 1,
  "Creator": 1,
  "Created": "2019-12-10T08:17:14-08:00",
  "Modified": "2019-12-11T06:11:18-08:00",
  "OnCost": 0,
  "StartTimeLocalized": "2019-12-13T09:00:00+02:00",
  "EndTimeLocalized": "2019-12-13T18:00:00+02:00",
  "ExternalId": null,
  "ConnectCreator": null,
  "AreaObject": {}
}];

const people = [{
    Id: 1,
    DisplayName: 'Lex Luthor',
    ContactObject: {
      Email: 'lexl@dc.com'
    }
  },
  {
    Id: 406,
    DisplayName: 'Clark Kent',
    ContactObject: {
      Email: 'clarkk@dc.com'
    }
  }
];

const result = _.map(all, v => _.merge(v, {
  PersonObject: _.find(people, p => p.Id === v.PersonId)
}));

console.log('result', result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```